# NLopt with univariate optimization

Tags: optimization, julia, nlopt

Anyone know if NLopt works with univariate optimization. Tried to run following code:

```
using NLopt

function myfunc(x, grad)
    x.^2
end

opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 1)
min_objective!(opt, myfunc)
(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [1.234])
println("got $minf at $minx (returned $ret)")
```

But get following error message:

```
> Error evaluating untitled
LoadError: BoundsError: attempt to access 1-element Array{Float64,1}:
1.234
at index [2]
in myfunc at untitled:8
in nlopt_callback_wrapper at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/NLopt/src/NLopt.jl:415
in optimize! at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/NLopt/src/NLopt.jl:514
in optimize at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/NLopt/src/NLopt.jl:520
in include_string at loading.jl:282
in include_string at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/CodeTools/src/eval.jl:32
in anonymous at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:84
in withpath at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/Requires/src/require.jl:37
in withpath at /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:53
[inlined code] from /Users/davidzentlermunro/.julia/v0.4/Atom/src/eval.jl:83
in anonymous at task.jl:58
while loading untitled, in expression starting on line 13
```

If this isn't possible, does anyone know if a univariate optimizer where I can specify bounds and an initial condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you're missing here.

1. You need to specify the gradient (i.e. first derivative) of your function within the function.  See the tutorial and examples on the [github page](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) for NLopt.  Not all optimization algorithms require this, but the one that you are using `LD_MMA` looks like it does.  See [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Algorithms) for a listing of the various algorithms and which require a gradient.
2. You should specify the tolerance for conditions you need before you "declare victory" ¹ (i.e. decide that the function is sufficiently optimized).  This is the `xtol_rel!(opt,1e-4)` in the example below.  See also the `ftol_rel!` for another way to specify a different tolerance condition.  According to the documentation, for example, `xtol_rel` will "stop when an optimization step (or an estimate of the optimum) changes every parameter by less than tol multiplied by the absolute value of the parameter." and `ftol_rel` will "stop when an optimization step (or an estimate of the optimum) changes the objective function value by less than tol multiplied by the absolute value of the function value. "  See [here](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Reference) under the "Stopping Criteria" section for more information on various options here.
3. The function that you are optimizing should have a unidimensional output.  In your example, your output is a vector (albeit of length 1).  (`x.^2` in your output denotes a vector operation and a vector output).  If you "objective function" doesn't ultimately output a unidimensional number, then it won't be clear what your optimization objective is (e.g. what does it mean to minimize a vector?  It's not clear, you could minimize the norm of a vector, for instance, but a whole vector - it isn't clear).

Below is a working example, based on your code.  Note that I included the printing output from the example on the github page, which can be helpful for you in diagnosing problems.

```
using NLopt    

count = 0 # keep track of # function evaluations    

function myfunc(x::Vector, grad::Vector)
    if length(grad) > 0
        grad[1] = 2*x[1]
    end    

    global count
    count::Int += 1
    println("f_$count($x)")    

    x[1]^2
end    

opt = Opt(:LD_MMA, 1)    

xtol_rel!(opt,1e-4)    

min_objective!(opt, myfunc)
(minf,minx,ret) = optimize(opt, [1.234])    

println("got $minf at $minx (returned $ret)")
```

¹ (In the words of optimization great Yinyu Ye.)