# How to use NLopt in Julia with equality_constraint

Tags: julia, nlopt

I'm struggling to amend the [Julia-specific tutorial on NLopt](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) to meet my needs and would be grateful if someone could explain what I'm doing wrong or failing to understand.

I wish to:

- Minimise the value of some objective function `myfunc(x)`; where
- `x` must lie in the unit hypercube (just 2 dimensions in the example below); and
- the sum of the elements of `x` must be one.

Below I make `myfunc` very simple - the square of the distance from `x` to `[2.0, 0.0]` so that the obvious correct solution to the problem is `x = [1.0,0.0]` for which `myfunc(x) = 1.0`. I have also added `println` statements so that I can see what the solver is doing.

```
testNLopt = function()

    origin = [2.0,0.0]
    n = length(origin)

    #Returns square of the distance between x and "origin", and amends grad in-place
    myfunc = function(x::Vector{Float64}, grad::Vector{Float64})
        if length(grad) > 0 
            grad = 2 .* (x .- origin)
        end
        xOut = sum((x .- origin).^2)
        println("myfunc: x = $x; myfunc(x) = $xOut; ∂myfunc/∂x = $grad")
        return(xOut)
    end

    #Constrain the sums of the x's to be 1...
    sumconstraint =function(x::Vector{Float64}, grad::Vector{Float64})
        if length(grad) > 0
            grad = ones(length(x)) 
        end
        xOut = sum(x) - 1
        println("sumconstraint: x = $x; constraint = $xOut; ∂constraint/∂x = $grad")
        return(xOut)
    end

    opt = Opt(:LD_SLSQP,n)

    lower_bounds!(opt, zeros(n))
    upper_bounds!(opt,ones(n))
    equality_constraint!(opt,sumconstraint,0)
    #xtol_rel!(opt,1e-4)
    xtol_abs!(opt,1e-8)

    min_objective!(opt, myfunc)
    maxeval!(opt,20)#to ensure code always terminates, remove this line when code working correctly?
    optimize(opt,ones(n)./n)
end
```

I have read [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37733740/nlopt-with-univariate-optimization) and documentation [here](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/NLopt.jl) and [here](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but still can't figure out what's wrong. Worryingly, each time I run `testNLopt` I see different behaviour, [as in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnhAG.png) including occasions when the solver uselessly evaluates `myfunc([NaN,NaN])` many times.

Comment: I have no answer, but `grad` does not get changed in place here. You have to use `.=` for that.

Comment: Perfect! using `.=` to assign grad in the two functions `myfunc` and `sumconstraint` fixes the example I posted and also the much-more-complex actual problem I'm working on. Many thanks.

Comment: So that's the actual solution to the question?

Comment: Yes it is. Do I need to mark the question as answered in some way?

Comment: I will post an answer, that's considered better than leaving this in the comments. You can then mark the answer as accepted (after some time, when the system lets you). Thanks for caring!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't actually writing to the `grad` parameters in-place, as you write in the comments;

```
grad = 2 .* (x .- origin)
```

just overrides the local variable, not the array contents -- and I guess that's why you see these `df/dx = [NaN, NaN]` everywhere.  The simplest way to fix that would be with broadcasting assignment (note the dot):

```
grad .= 2 .* (x .- origin)
```

and so on.  You can read about that behaviour [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#Argument-Passing-Behavior-1) and [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1).